# ORA-06530 Reference to Uninitialized Composite error in PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, types, procedure

I have a procedure as below.

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY       "DTS_INVOICE_RESEARCH_PKG" AS 

PROCEDURE DO_RESEARCH (IN_ROW_TBL       IN OUT NOCOPY       DTS.DTS_CARRIER_ROW_TBL,
                       OUT_ROW_VARRAY   IN OUT NOCOPY       DTS.DTS_CARRIER_ROW_RETURN_VARRAY)
AS
    TYPE CARRIER_ROW_REC_COLLECTION IS TABLE OF DTS.DTS_CARRIER_ROW_REC INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);
    
    COUNTER         INTEGER := 0;
    TRACKING_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50);
    ROW_COLLECTION  CARRIER_ROW_REC_COLLECTION; --K,V pair of tracking number and CARRIER_ROW_REC
    
    --This cursor finds all tracking numbers which already exist in the INVOICE_CARTON table
    --If they already exist, that means the tracking number was previously invoiced
    CURSOR C1 IS
    SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ TRACKING_NUMBER
    FROM DTS.DTS_INVOICE_CARTON
    WHERE TRACKING_NUMBER IN 
    (SELECT TRACKING_NUMBER FROM TABLE(IN_ROW_TBL));

    CURSOR C2 IS
    select do.PROMISE_DATE, do.CUSTOMER_ID
                , do.region_id, upper(trim(dm.market)) market
                , count(do.CUSTOMER_ID) carton_count
                , dc.TRACKING_NUMBER TRACKING_NUMBER
        from dts.dts_order_container dc,
             dts.dts_order do,
             dts.dts_route_matrix dm,
             dts.dts_invoice_ctr ct
        where ct.region_id = dm.region_id
        and   ct.market_id = dm.market_id
        and   ct.vendor_id = dm.carrier_id
        and   dm.region_id = do.region_id
        and   dm.route_id = do.route_id
        and do.order_number = dc.order_number
        and dm.carrier_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT dm.CARRIER_ID FROM TABLE(IN_ROW_TBL))
        and dm.active = 'Y' --William, ensures we only reference active RM rows, fixes NAIT-28235
        and dm.carrier_mode not in ('LTL','USPS','PF','OTHER','Other','UPS')
        and do.ORDER_NUMBER in (SELECT DISTINCT do.ORDER_NUMBER FROM TABLE(IN_ROW_TBL))
        and upper(trim(dm.market)) not like 'FURNITURE' --remove any markets that have 'furniture' in them
        group by do.PROMISE_DATE, do.CUSTOMER_ID, do.region_id, upper(trim(dm.market)), dc.tracking_number
        having count(do.CUSTOMER_ID) = 1
        order by do.PROMISE_DATE, do.REGION_ID, upper(trim(dm.market)), do.CUSTOMER_ID;
        
    C1_REC          C1%ROWTYPE;
    C2_REC          C2%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

  OUT_ROW_VARRAY := DTS.DTS_CARRIER_ROW_RETURN_VARRAY();
  OUT_ROW_VARRAY.EXTEND (IN_ROW_TBL.COUNT);
  
  --Loops through the input table to create a collection for easy object updating
  FOR IDX1 IN 1..IN_ROW_TBL.COUNT LOOP
  
    --Stores the payable order statuses for each tracking number, if applicable
    --The storing happens before the object is transferred into the collection
    BEGIN
      SELECT NVL(TO_NUMBER(ORDER_STATUS, '99'), 0)
      INTO IN_ROW_TBL(IDX1).ORDER_STATUS --sets the current object's edi status
      FROM DTS.DTS_ORDER_STATUS_LOG
      WHERE ORDER_NUMBER = IN_ROW_TBL(IDX1).ORDER_NUMBER
      AND TRACKING_NUMBER = IN_ROW_TBL(IDX1).TRACKING_NUMBER
      AND ORDER_STATUS IN ('50','51','52','07')
      AND ROWNUM < 2; --ensures we don't get multple results and choke
      
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          NULL;
    END;
    
    ROW_COLLECTION(IN_ROW_TBL(IDX1).TRACKING_NUMBER) := IN_ROW_TBL(IDX1);
  END LOOP;
  
  --Loop through the cursor, and update the invoiced flag of whichever tracking numbers
  --are returned by the cursor
  OPEN C1;
  LOOP
  FETCH C1 INTO C1_REC;
  EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
    --SET THE INVOICED FLAG FOR THE CARRIER_REC WHICH IS ASSOCIATED WITH THE TRACKING NUMBER WE FOUND
    ROW_COLLECTION(C1_REC.TRACKING_NUMBER).INVOICED := 1; --INVOICED SHOULD EITHER BE 1 OR 0, SETTING TO 1 MEANS INVOICED
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;
  
  OPEN C2;
  LOOP
  FETCH C2 INTO C2_REC;
  EXIT WHEN C2%NOTFOUND;
    --SET THE INVOICED FLAG FOR THE CARRIER_REC WHICH IS ASSOCIATED WITH THE TRACKING NUMBER WE FOUND
    ROW_COLLECTION(C2_REC.TRACKING_NUMBER).IS_SINGLE_CARTON := 1; --INVOICED SHOULD EITHER BE 1 OR 0, SETTING TO 1 MEANS INVOICED   -- getting error at this line
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C2;
  
  --These are both control variables for iterating through the collection and storing
  --the CARRIER_ROW objects in the output array
  TRACKING_NUMBER := ROW_COLLECTION.FIRST;
  COUNTER := 1;
  
  --Loop through the collection to copy the ROW_REC objects into the output varray
  WHILE TRACKING_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
  LOOP
    OUT_ROW_VARRAY(COUNTER) := ROW_COLLECTION(TRACKING_NUMBER);
    
    TRACKING_NUMBER := ROW_COLLECTION.NEXT(TRACKING_NUMBER);
    COUNTER := COUNTER + 1;
  END LOOP;
  
END DO_RESEARCH;
    
END DTS_INVOICE_RESEARCH_PKG;
```

-> One object type as :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "DTS"."DTS_CARRIER_ROW_REC" FORCE AS OBJECT
(
    ORDER_NUMBER VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) ,
    TRACKING_NUMBER VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) ,
    ROW_NUMBER INT ,
    INVOICED INT ,
    ORDER_STATUS INT ,
    CARRIER_ID VARCHAR2(20) ,
    IS_SINGLE_CARTON INT
);
```

For above mentioned procedure, I am getting error at cursor C2. Error:  Error Msg =

```
ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite
ORA-06512: at "DTS.DTS_INVOICE_RESEARCH_PKG", line 89
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Please help me how to fix this error. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please reduce to code and show only relevant part for this error. Another tip: Use modern ANSI join syntax instead of old Oracle join syntax. Why do you store numbers as strings? (e.g. column `ORDER_STATUS`). Using `IN (SELECT DISTINCT ...)` is useless, skip `DISTINCT`. I did not analyze your code in detail, however I assume you can do it without the loops. I am quite sure you will not need run four loops.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from several weaknesses in your package (see my comment), it looks like you call the procedure with uninitialized value.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE DTS_CARRIER_ROW_TBL AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DO_RESEARCH(IN_ROW_TBL IN DTS_CARRIER_ROW_TBL) IS
BEGIN   
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Result: ' || IN_ROW_TBL.COUNT );
END;
/
```

And the call:

```
DECLARE
    IN_ROW_TBL DTS_CARRIER_ROW_TBL;
BEGIN
    DO_RESEARCH(IN_ROW_TBL);
END;

ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at "DO_RESEARCH", line 3
ORA-06512: at line 4


DECLARE
    IN_ROW_TBL DTS_CARRIER_ROW_TBL := DTS_CARRIER_ROW_TBL();
BEGIN
    DO_RESEARCH(IN_ROW_TBL);
END;

Result: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

your ROW_COLLECTION is an associative array of DTS.DTS_CARRIER_ROW_REC which are `object` and requires initialization,so just add

```
if not ROW_COLLECTION.exists(C1_REC.TRACKING_NUMBER)
   then ROW_COLLECTION(C1_REC.TRACKING_NUMBER) := DTS.DTS_CARRIER_ROW_REC(null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
end if;
```

if you want to initialize it with nulls or

```
if not ROW_COLLECTION.exists(C1_REC.TRACKING_NUMBER)
   then ROW_COLLECTION(C1_REC.TRACKING_NUMBER) := IN_ROW_TBL(C1_REC.TRACKING_NUMBER);
```

if it must get initial values from IN_ROW_TBL.

before lines #80 and #89:

```
    ROW_COLLECTION(C1_REC.TRACKING_NUMBER).INVOICED := 1; --INVOICED SHOULD EITHER BE 1 OR 0, SETTING TO 1 MEANS INVOICED
```

```
    ROW_COLLECTION(C2_REC.TRACKING_NUMBER).IS_SINGLE_CARTON := 1; --INVOICED SHOULD EITHER BE 1 OR 0, SETTING TO 1 MEANS INVOICED   -- getting error at this line
```